# The method getNextQuote() is undefined for the type QuoteServerThread

Tags: java, networking, datagram

I am following a tutorial about Datagram Networkings on Java. I am creating the UDP Server, I copied the code on the website, but it says that it couldnt find getNextQuote() this function. I was wondering what is wrong here?

```
public void run(){

    while(moreQuotes){

        try{

    byte[] buf = new byte[256];

    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf,buf.length);

    socket.receive(packet);

    InetAddress address = packet.getAddress();

    int port = packet.getPort();

    String dString = null;

    if (in == null)

        dString = new Date().toString();

    else

        dString = getNextQuote();

    buf = dString.getBytes();

    DatagramPacket newPacket = new DatagramPacket(buf,buf.length,address,port);

    socket.send(newPacket);

        } catch(IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            moreQuotes = false;

        }
```

Comment: Is there getNextQuote() method/function in this class (which is named QuoteServerThread, I guess)? Paste the code of the whole class.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes, it's just that the tutorial does not include the implement of that function. I thought it was written in the class already. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should copy all functions of class from the tutorial? I past your code to google and find this [link which contains whole implementation](http://gauss.ececs.uc.edu/Courses/c694/lectures/java/QuoteClient/QS.java.html):

```
private String getNextQuote()
{
    String returnValue = null;
    try
    {
        if ((returnValue = qfs.readLine()) == null)
        {
            qfs.close();
            this.openInputFile();
            returnValue = qfs.readLine();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        returnValue = "IOException occurred in server.";
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The tutorial does not include this function! I got it!